# Streaming the output to the file is not working

Tags: shell

I write a simple shell script like:

```
marco () {
      echo "$(pwd)" > /tmp/missimg/marco.txt
}
```

But it's not working as I expected. I want to redirect the output of echo to the marco.txt file, but marco.txt's content stay unchanged. How is that?

Comment: It shouldn't be. Are you sure you're looking at the right `marco.txt`? As an aside, `echo "$(pwd)"` can just be written `pwd`.

Comment: Yes, I am looking at the right marco.txt.

Comment: Each time you invoke the function, it will overwrite the output file.  The output of only the last execution of the function will be left in the file when the script is done.

Comment: @chepner.  Almost.  Imagine if the output of `pwd` is the string `-e`.  (Of course, in that case there are other issues that need to be addressed!)

Comment: Can you please describe what you do with the code you post? Do you put it in a file? Do you write it in a shell? Do you invoke the function after you define it?

Comment: After calling the function `marco` still nothing happens when the real subdir is `/tmp/missing` and not `/tmp/missimg`.

Answer (score 1):

If that piece of code is all the content your script has, it is actually doing *nothing* when you run it, because what you did is only declaring a function, but for that to work you then should *call* it later on your code. If that is the case, try:

```
#!/bin/bash

marco () {
      echo "$(pwd)" > /tmp/missimg/marco.txt
}

marco
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the first line and the last line. Could you explain it for a little bit?

Comment: The first line is a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), and the last one is the way you invoke the function you previously declared.